How to secure a route using JWT in nodeJs?
I want to make a route (/homepage) only accessible when the user is logged in, but I can't manage to.
Basically, I coded an auth module using JWT and MongoDB, and right now, I'm stuck on making a page only accessible if logged in.
It actually works, the token is stored in localstorage, and the authMiddleware return a successfull status. But the thing is, I'm still not able to go on /homepage when logged in (it says: authentification required on the page)
I think I should change my whole logged in verification system.
I'm genuienly lost, so I'll give all the files of my project. However, the most importants are probably the authMiddleware.js ; server.js ; signin.js ones.
authController.js :
require('dotenv').config();

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/User');

exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        const user = await User.create({ name, password: hashedPassword });
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });
        res.status(201).json({ token });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create user' });
    }
};

exports.checkAlreadyExists = async (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ name });
        if (user) {
            res.status(200).json({ exists: true });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ exists: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to check if user exists' });
    }
};

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ name });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }
        const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
        if (!isMatch) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });
        res.status(200).json({ token });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to login' });
    }
};


authMiddleware.js :
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Authorization Header:', req.headers['authorization']);
    
    const token = req.headers['authorization']?.split(' ')[1];
    
    if (!token) {
        console.log('No token found');
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No token provided' });
    }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Token verification failed:', err);
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Failed to authenticate token' });
        }

        req.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
    });
};

module.exports = isAuthenticated;


authRoutes.js :
// authRoute.js

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const { signup, login, checkAlreadyExists } = require('../controllers/authController');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', signup);

router.post('/checkAlreadyExists', checkAlreadyExists);

router.post('/login', login);

module.exports = router;


server.js :
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoute');
const isAuthenticated = require('./middleware/authMiddleware');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/signup.html');
});

app.get('/verifyToken', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Token is valid' });
});

app.get('/homepage', isAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/homepage.html');
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


signin.js :
        document.getElementById('signin-form').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/auth/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ name, password }),
                });


                const data = await response.json();
                if (response.ok) {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                    const isSignedIn = await fetch('/homepage', {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${data.token}`
                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    
                    alert(data.error);
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur:', error);
                alert('Une erreur est survenue. Veuillez réessayer.');
            }
        });

I know this aint no easy task, so really, thank you.
PS : Some other post talks about that, but I don't think it really adapts to my code.

Alright I better understand what's your issue now ;
You are using JsonWebToken, and usually these tokens aren't defined as session token.
This means they aren't sent with your requests, they are usually sent through Authorization header ; and retrieved from WWW-Authenticate header within the response.
You might take a look at this answer

So, to send your token for each request and be able to access /homepage with a simple GET, you may use cookies instead (see this answer) (server-side, within authController.js and/or authMiddleware.js) ;
// server.js
app.use(express.cookieParser());

// And within your function signup(), login() and/or isAuthenticated()
res.cookie('token', tokenValue, { maxAge: 10000, httpOnly: true });


Previous answer
That's because you don't go through isAuthenticated() middleware ;
You might want something like this ;
app.use('/homepage', isAuthenticated);

app.get('/homepage', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/homepage.html');
});

And add to the top of authMiddleware.js ;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config();

[...]

Just like you did for authController.js, to access your environment variables.

Thank you for answering! I added that in server.js, but how about the client side (signin.js)? Is there anything to change? What do I have to adapt? Cause right now, just by using this, logging in, and going to /homepage, I've still an error.

What's the error ?

Same as before. I go on /homepage, and it says I'm not authentificated.  The problem is, each time I try to access /homepage, it requires token, but i don't know how to send that token each time i go to /homepage...
